# Using class without alloc

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to understand JitsiMeet iOS code and I noticed that they have init the class **without doing something like this**

```
[[JitsiMeetView alloc] setPropsInViews:[conferenceOptions asProps]]
```

Instead they did

```
return [JitsiMeetView setPropsInViews:[conferenceOptions asProps]];
```

Code: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeet.m#L117

There JitsiMeetView is imported as

```
#import "JitsiMeetView+Private.h"
```

Where this is the interface of Jetsi Meet
#import `"JitsiMeetView.h"`

```
@interface JitsiMeetView ()

+ (instancetype _Nullable)viewForExternalAPIScope:(NSString *_Nonnull)externalAPIScope;
+ (BOOL)setPropsInViews:(NSDictionary *_Nonnull)newProps;

@end
```

Link: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView%2BPrivate.h

Also, I can't see `JitsiMeetView+Private.m`. Can someone please explain me how to above logic works? for Jitsi?

Comment: Why did you tag this swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have not "init the class". As the `+` indicates, this is a *class* method. It is called on the class, not on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`+` indicates that it is a class method and operates on the class itself.

While

`-` indicates that it is an instance method and operates on objects.

---

For example,

```
@interface MyClass ()

-(void)function1;

+(void)function2;

@end
```

---

function1 is an instance method. To call function1, use this code:

```
[[[MyClass alloc] init] function1];
```

function2 is a class method. To call function2, use this code:

```
[MyClass function2];
```